# Echo number of records in row with COUNT()

Tags: php, sql

How to get and echo number of records in row?this is my code

```
$b = "SELECT COUNT(Users) FROM room";
$r= mysqli_query($connection,$b);
$c = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
echo $c['Users'];
```

I get this error while i have it in `room` table

> Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\blog0\rooms.php on
>   line 31

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(Users) as Users FROM room`

Comment: Add an alias to your SQL query: `SELECT COUNT(Users) AS user_cnt FROM room` then `echo $c['user_cnt'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple answer (And one I made in the past)
You forgot to name the count, it's becomes a system variable and very hard to remember

Change the select to

```
 SELECT COUNT(Users) AS Users FROM room
```

Comment: "And one I made in the past"? Couldn't you flag the question as a duplicate, then? (I get it can be kind of hard to find our old answers if you can't remember exactly when it was, though.)

Comment: What I mean is this is some error I made constantly in the past, I didn't answer it in the past.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I remember getting tripped up by that too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting MySQL do the counting, get the data and let php [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) do the work.

Change:

```
$b = "SELECT COUNT(Users) FROM room";
$r= mysqli_query($connection,$b);
$c = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
echo $c['Users'];
```

To:

```
$b = "SELECT `Users` FROM room";
$r= mysqli_query($connection,$b);
$c = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
echo count($c['Users']);
```

removed `COUNT(Users)` and replaced it with `Users` and added `count()` to `count($c['Users']);`

Comment: Wouldn't counting in MySQL be more efficient, though? Why would we want to change that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic not that i know of, from what i can say is that its less stress on the server to call to the MySQL db and then count. My method you only calling the MySQL db and then letting php do a quick count with data that is already there.